# Should I use additional container in my MVVM project?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

**Source to the sample project:** https://github.com/AntwanReno/navi

I did a project in WPF MVVM. It has three sub-projects: WPF app, ViewModels (PCL) and Domain (PCL). WPF is just a single `Window` with single `Frame` and two `Pages`. I will present the code, but recommend to clone/fork my prepared sample in repo.

Here is the code for WPF Client:

**App.xaml.cs**

```
namespace NaviWPFApp
{
    using System.Windows;
    using NaviWPFApp.Views;
    using NaviWPFApp.Views.Pages;   

    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public static NavigationService Navigation; 

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);  

            MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
            mainWindow.Show();  

            Navigation = new NavigationService(mainWindow.MyFrame);
            Navigation.Navigate<FirstPage>();
        }
    }
}
```

**App.xaml** It's just:

```
<Application x:Class="NaviWPFApp.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:NaviWPFApp"
             x:Name="Application">
    <Application.Resources>
        <local:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I Have one main window with frame, and two very similar pages (no code-behind):

```
<Window x:Class="NaviWPFApp.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="NaviWPFApp" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Frame x:Name="MyFrame" Margin="10" />
    </Grid>
</Window>   

<Page x:Class="NaviWPFApp.Views.FirstPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Title="FirstPage" 
      DataContext="{Binding FirstPageViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}">
    <Grid>
        <Button Command="{Binding GoToSecondPageCommand}"  Height="30" Content="Go to second page" />
    </Grid>
</Page> 


<Page x:Class="NaviWPFApp.Views.SecondPage"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
      Title="SecondPage"
      DataContext="{Binding Path=SecondPageViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLocator}}">
    <StackPanel Margin="0, 100, 0, 0">
        <Button Command="{Binding CountSomethingCommand}" Content="Count something" Height="30" />
        <Button Command="{Binding BackToFirstPageCommand}" Content="Go back to page 1" Height="30" />
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

I my client I have also two additional classes ViewModelLocator and NavigationService - used for naviation between pages:

```
namespace NaviWPFApp
{
    using NaviWPFApp.ViewModels.Pages;  

    public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        public FirstPageViewModel FirstPageViewModel => new FirstPageViewModel(App.Navigation);
        public SecondPageViewModel SecondPageViewModel => new SecondPageViewModel(App.Navigation);
    }
}   

namespace NaviWPFApp
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Reflection;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using NaviWPFApp.ViewModels.Common; 

    public class NavigationService : INavigationService
    {
        readonly Frame frame;   

        public NavigationService(Frame frame)
        {
            this.frame = frame;
        }   

        public void GoBack()
        {
            frame.GoBack();
        }   

        public void GoForward()
        {
            frame.GoForward();
        }   

        public bool Navigate(string page)
        {
            var type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes().SingleOrDefault(a => a.Name.Equals(page));
            if (type == null) return false; 

            var src = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            return frame.Navigate(src);
        }

        public bool Navigate<T>(object parameter = null)
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            return Navigate(type, parameter);
        }

        public bool Navigate(Type source, object parameter = null)
        {
            var src = Activator.CreateInstance(source);
            return frame.Navigate(src, parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here is my **ViewModels (Portable)** project:

It's only two ViewModel classes for each Page in UI, INavigationService (I don't want to know anything about NavigationService implementation and UI client), MyObservableObject and MyCommand.

`MyObservableObject` and `MyCommand` are typical implementations of `INotifyPropertyChanged` and `ICommand` interfaces.

So this is an interface and two viewmodels:

```
public interface INavigationService
{
    void GoForward();
    void GoBack();
    bool Navigate(string page);
}


namespace NaviWPFApp.ViewModels
{
    public class FirstPageViewModel : MyObservableObject
    {
        private readonly INavigationService navigationService;

        public FirstPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
        {
            this.navigationService = navigationService;
        }

        public MyCommand GoToSecondPageCommand
        {
            get { return new MyCommand(x => navigationService.Navigate("SecondPage")); }
        }
    }
}   

namespace NaviWPFApp.ViewModels
{
    public class SecondPageViewModel : MyObservableObject
    {
        private readonly INavigationService navigationService;
        private readonly BusinessLogic businessLogic;   

        public SecondPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService, BusinessLogic businessLogic = null)
        {
            this.navigationService = navigationService;
            this.businessLogic = businessLogic;
        }   

        public MyCommand BackToFirstPageCommand
        {
            get { return new MyCommand(x => navigationService.Navigate("FirstPage")); }
        }   

        public MyCommand CountSomethingCommand
        {
            get { return new MyCommand(x => businessLogic?.CountSomething()); }
        }
    }
}
```

And my Business logic, just this:

```
public class BusinessLogic
{
    private int counter = 0;

    public bool CountSomething()
    {
        return ++counter > 10;
    }
}
```

Dependencies are simple: **Domain** knows nothing, besides its own operations, **ViewModel** knows about Domain, but nothing about View and **View**... well, here is my problem - it knows about ViewModel, but should View know about Domain? I will explain my concerns, but here is what I meant:

[image]

**First concern:** As you can see, the navigation is all done in ViewModel, and Business logic is used only in second page view model. SecondPage view doesn't need to know about the logic.

**Second concern:** Because I'm trying to stick with dependency injection, I want to create my domain object (which I need only one) at the beginning of the program. So in `protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)`, so in VIEW. And I have no idea, how to pass it to second view model, which is created in `ViewModelLocator`.

So my question is: How to convert this code, so it will be more ViewModel orientated? I want just inject my Domain object into ViewModel (where it belongs), not into View.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: tl;dr; Sorry, dude. What was your question? Looks like you are already using view-models. So I don't see what you are asking.

Comment: I can't answer your question but can I recommend using [caliburn.micro](http://caliburnmicro.com/) which is a lightweight MVVM framework. Some design questions are automatically solved by using it. It brings its own IoC container and many other useful features.

Answer (score 2):

You can't aviod that dependency because `App.OnStartup` is a composition root, which means `App.OnStartup` knows about everything.
But, what you can avoid is this global prop in your App: `public static NavigationService Navigation;`. You can simply inject it into the object where you will need it.

> First concern: As you can see, the navigation is all done in
>   ViewModel, and Business logic is used only in second page view model.
>   SecondPage view doesn't need to know about the logic.

SecondPage doen't have to know about business object. App must know. So you can inject you object into locator and locator can inject this object into specific ViewModel when the time comes.

> Second concern: Because I'm trying to stick with dependency injection,
>   I want to create my domain object (which I need only one) at the
>   beginning of the program. So in protected override void
>   OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e), so in VIEW. And I have no idea, how to
>   pass it to second view model, which is created in ViewModelLocator.

Dependency injection.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
public class ViewModelLocator
{
    private NavigationService navigationService;
    private BusinessLogic businessLogic;
    public void InjectNavigationService(NavigationService navigation)
    {
        navigationService = navigation;
    } 
    public void InjectBusinessLogic(BusinessLogic logic)
    {
        businessLogic = logic;
    } 

    public FirstPageViewModel FirstPageViewModel => new FirstPageViewModel(navigationService);
    public SecondPageViewModel SecondPageViewModel => new SecondPageViewModel(navigationService, businessLogic);
}

public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        // Create/resolve all your objects in Comoposition Root:
        var businessLogic = new BusinessLogic();

        // Here you will have locator created already, but mainWindow has not been created yet
        // Retrive your locator
        ViewModelLocator locator = Resources.Values.OfType<ViewModelLocator>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (locator == null)
            throw new NoNullAllowedException("ViewModelLocator cannot be null.");

        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        var navigation = new NavigationService(mainWindow.MyFrame);

        // Inject your logic and navigation into locator
        locator.InjectBusinessLogic(businessLogic);
        locator.InjectNavigationService(navigation);

        // Set up first page
        navigation.Navigate<FirstPage>();

        // and show the window
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is, you can't avoid it, especially not if you use Dependency Injection/IoC container (which is recommended to decouple your code and increase testability).

The reason why you can't avoid it, is because (when using IoC) you'll need to inject your dependencies via constructor (or less than optimal, via Properties/Methods). Most IoC container require these to be public.

Since most of the types injected this way are not in your ViewModel PCL, but in your model (domain) and publicly visible, a reference to the assembly is required, even if you don't manually initialize your ViewModels.

Your confusion comes from the term "View". Your WPF Project has more than one role though in this case.

1. It represents your view layer with all the views (XAML files)
2. Also your application code is inside the very same project/assembly. Application code is stuff like `NavigationServce` implementation (`INavigationService` interface however belongs to ViewModel assembly)

While your views don't need any references to your domain class, your application does (Composition root, DI/IoC container).